# Pass a JavaScript Variable into Rails Scripting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

This may have been asked before and i can not find anything that would work yet

I am tring to pass a little bit of information into a button that will forward a user to another page.

```
function addMultiple(){
    var id = $("#truck_company_id").val();
    //dont really want to do this: 
    //window.location.replace("http://www.website.com/companies/"+id+"/trucks");
    //want to do it this way so will work in development
    window.location = <%= trucks_company_path(id) %>;
}
```

all i need to do is direct a user to the correct website after they click this button.

```
<button id="class-list" onclick="addMultiple()" class="btn btn-warning pull-right" style="margin: 0;">Add Multiple Trucks</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either get rid of Rails using concatenation of strings:

```
window.location = '/companies/' + id + '/trucks'
```

or use a Gem like [this one](https://github.com/railsware/js-routes)

Answer (score 0):

Output the path as a data-attribute server side and then retrieve it from the script.

```
<button data-redirect-url="http://www.website.com/companies/xx/trucks"  id="class-list addMultipleTrucks" class="btn btn-warning pull-right">Add Multiple Trucks</button>

$('#multipleTrucks').click(function(){
    window.location = $(this).data('redirect-url');
});
```

Comment: the thing is the ID changes... it is in a drop down list.. also this is not very friendly to development

Comment: Render the output of trucks_company_path(id)  as data-redirect-url for every id/option in the dropdown list. When you submit the form, redirect to the data-redirect-url of the currently selected option in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Big Al Ruby Newbie, you can't use java-script variable into rails.

So you can use 'data' attribute to get the URL then simply pass id.